Esav - Patriarch of Nations?
I was listening to HaRav Mendel Kessin shlita and he brought the idea that Esav is a failed Av/Patriarch of the Jewish people.
My question is, is there a concept that he is considered to be in some way an Av HaGoyim? Similar to Bilaam being a prophet for the nations, perhaps they have also been given an Av. Esav's legacy is meant to do teshuva, and  he is in many ways father of the west, so it's not such an outlandish idea, and therefore I thought I'd ask here, and if so please provide me some further reading.

ראשית גוים עמלק

I have noticed a few western (usually ex-Christian) Noahides have a strong interest in learning about Esav, as if they view him as some sort of patriarch. FWIW

See Bereshit 17:4 and tractate Brachot 16b. תָּנוּ רַבָּנַן: אֵין קוֹרִין ״אָבוֹת״ אֶלָּא לִשְׁלֹשָׁה, וְאֵין קוֹרִין ״אִמָּהוֹת״ אֶלָּא לְאַרְבַּע.

@YaacovDeane thank you my teacher and friend! עד הכא חשיבי, טפי לא חשיבי. Esav is not ruled out by this principle. As for Bereshit, do you recommend a particular commentary because this, taken at face value, could be used as evidence that Esav is some form of an Av?

Hello my friend. The Shas definitely excludes Eisav. We only call three by the appellation of “Avot”, Avraham, Yitzchok and Yaacov. Regarding the commentaries to the quote from Bereshit, I know you are a busy man, so I will tell you what the Lubavitcher Rebbe told an  individual in similar circumstances. You can leave off the Acharonim.  Only blessings for good RabbiKaii.

@YaacovDeane the gemara definitely rules him out from being Av Yisrael. Lol. Ok, I'll try and learn all the Rishonim bli neder

Just to emphasize, the statement from Shas does not use a qualifier restricting it only to Yisrael for the term Avot. If you think about this for a minute, all Noahides only get their connection to the seven commandments of Noah via Moshe Rabbeinu and the giving of the 10 commandments at Har Sinai. That is the tradition that Moshe argued with G-d about allowing the erev Rav to leave Egypt. They could only come along because of their connection via the Avot and specifically Avraham. Those Mitzrim, for example, who didn't claim that, were drowned at the Yam Suf.
